# Plain text editor (or plugin) with ability to copy line into clipboard in just one mouse click

Tags: text-editor

I'm looking for plain text editor (or plugin) with ability to stay on top and copy entire single line into clipboard by just clicking somewhere within this line. Without need to make a selection or press any key(s) first, just click and get line copied into clipboard. Next click inside editor's window gets another line from opened file copied into clipboard, and so on. Thanks.

Comment: Since you reference a *stay on top* editor do you mean the editor will be copying data from outside of itself (i.e. from other applications)? 

That would be very difficult to achieve as there is no easy way for one application to read data from another using nothing but the location of the mouse cursor.
    
But to have that functionality work just inside the editor itself should be doable, provided the editor is scriptable, but most editors are not *stay on top*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such app exists. Coz single click always changes caret position only. 
In SynWrite editor u can click line, AND press Ctrl+C. (First set option "Copy current line if no selection made" on).